# Heroku Connection Leaks after postgres update v297

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework

We are having problems with our database that looks like leaks. After investigating the problem we found out that the only change was a postgres update on 29.05.2018 with the version v297.
We are running a Play! application with Hikari as connection pool. The error that is repeating in our logs states:

> java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: [OurPoolName] - Connection
>   is not available, request timed out after 3000ms.

Comment: I am having the same issue, would you happen to have found a solution by any chance?

Comment: The problem was solved in a later release. At the time, we hade to rollback Postgres to an older version. I think you can do that by rolling back to a point before that update was deployed on your application.